# Using passwordless ssh on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, selinux

I have a fresh install of CentOS 6 that I am trying to connect to using ssh without a password.

But each time I try to login, I am asked for the password.

Here are the commands in order:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i ./id_rsa.pub user@192.168.1.20
ssh user@192.168.1.20
restorecon -r .ssh
```

Comment: Check output of `ssh -v` - it should mention sending the key and what was the outcome of that action. Checking server-side (`sshd`) log should give you even more clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the permissions of `~user/.ssh` and particularly the owner.
IIRC If the owner is `root`, `user` running `restorecon` cannot change it.

You also should edit `~/.ssh/authorizedkeys` as `ssh-copy-id` recommends and make sure that only the expected public key is in that file.

(If that does not help, post `ls -ld ~user/.ssh` and `ls -l ~user/.ssh`)

Comment: It was a permission error. I mistakenly thought that restorecon would correct permissions, but it looks like ~/.ssh/authorized_keys was 664 and it *must* be 600. Or, at least it worked after chmodding to 600 without doing anything else.

Comment: Just to add a bit to the discussion, `restorecon` is used to restore the SElinux context, not for changing the ugo/rwx permissions.